# data frame export into excel/csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have created a data frame on python using melt function and other functions the final data frame i got is about 3 million rows. I need to export the data frame into excel/csv file. Which code could afford the 3M rows in the dataset.

Code i have used to export is:

```
World_bank.to_csv(r'C:\Users\ITM\Documents\Gaurav Pandey\World Bank\WBSDG\World_Bank_DIET.csv')
```

But this is not exporting the entire dataframe.

Suggest me some code which can export the large dataframe into the multiple excel sheets so that i can read entire data points.

Comment: Excel isn't CSV. They're *completely* different formats. CSV is just text with minimal formatting and no types. Excel is a ZIP package containing XML files with a specific schema and specific types for strings, numbers and dates (in a way). As for exporting 3M rows to a single file, Excel has a hard limit of 1M rows per sheet. There may be many sheets in a single workbook, but none of them can have more than 1M rows

Comment: Tip: don't use Excel for large amounts of data like this. But really, CSV and Excel are not the same.